# How can I get position of a screen text with python?

Tags: python, bots, python-tesseract

I need to write a program that press a button, so python have to find the text of the button on the screen and it needs to find the position of this button to press it. But I can do this?

I searched a lot on google, but I don't find an answer.
I only use pytesseract to find the text on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can do binary search:

1. Divide your screen in two
2. Use `pytesseract`to know in which half the wanted text is.
3. Divide it again in two.
4. Repeat step 2

Another way to do it, if the screen is your browser, is use `HTML`, find the button using `re`(Regular expressions), get the link which button calls (normally it's a javascript function). Then you can call it to artificially click on the button.